# In Kotlin, how do I create a list of lambdas where each lambda is of the type (Int) -> List? I'm getting destructuring declaration errors

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a list of lambdas in Kotlin, but am getting the following compile-time error:

```
 Destructuring declaration initializer of type Int must have a 'component1()' function
```

Here is my code:

```kotlin
val pathXRanges = listOf<(Int) -> List<Int>>(
                {(extX) -> ((extX - (board.k - 1))..(extX + board.k - 1)).toList()}, // diagonal 1 (y = -x)
                {(extX) -> ((extX - (board.k - 1))..(extX + board.k - 1)).toList()}, // diagonal 2 (y = x)
                {(extX) -> List(board.k * 2 - 2) { extX } }, // x = x
                {(extX) -> ((extX - (board.k - 1))..(extX + board.k - 1)).toList()} // y = y
        )
```

That's pretty much it! Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need clarification on anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply remove the brackets from the `extX` lambda parameter values i.e.:

```
    val pathXRanges = listOf<(Int) -> List<Int>>(
      { extX -> ((extX - (board.k - 1))..(extX + board.k - 1)).toList() }, // diagonal 1 (y = -x)
      { extX -> ((extX - (board.k - 1))..(extX + board.k - 1)).toList() }, // diagonal 2 (y = x)
      { extX -> List(board.k * 2 - 2) { extX } }, // x = x
      { extX -> ((extX - (board.k - 1))..(extX + board.k - 1)).toList() } // y = y
    )
```

The brackets indicate to the compiler that the lambda parameter should be [destructured](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-in-lambdas-since-11), and the parameter's `component1()` operator function should be called to assign a value to `extX`.

Of course, `Int` does not have a `component1()` function, hence the error:

```
Destructuring declaration initializer of type Int must have a 'component1()' function`.
```